# utf8 input encoding with biblatex (biber and bibencoding=utf8)

Tags: biblatex, input-encodings

I have a document with Cyrillic, English and German. All worked well so far. But now I need a special Character in the bibliography.bib file. Its an `\.{E}`

If I just put that in there it gives me the following error:

`! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:Ė not set up for use with LaTeX.`

Here's a sample code that reproduces that behavior:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english,russian,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{onebook.bib}
@book{eichenbaum,
author={{\.{E}}jchenbaum},
title={Wie Gogol's \enquote{Mantel} gemacht ist},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{onebook.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\.{E}jchenbaum

Гоголь

Münze

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If I put a regular `E` in that .bib file, I get the following (and correct encoding as I want it outside the bibliography):

[image: without special character in .bib]

If I put that `\.{E}` in the .bib file and I comment out the line:
`% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
Then I get the following:

[image: with special char in .bib file]

So the funny thing is, I can get the bibliography interact with my document file at the cost of losing encoding of regular text in there ...

As always, I appreciate any kind of help! Thanks!

Comment: `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and `\newunicodechar{Ė}{\.{E}}` should do.

Comment: Ha! :insane laughter: So fast! So working! Thanks an awful  lot!

Comment: With `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec` (and  a font that contains all the glyphs such as Minion Pro) I have no problem to compile.

Comment: @ Bernard: I'll try that some day I have more time to look into it. Thanx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote the `newunicodechar` just for solving similar problems, due to the fact that the Unicode support of `inputenc` is limited (but extendable).

You can do in two ways:

1. Look up in the Unicode table to find that Ė is U+0116 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH DOT ABOVE and add to your preamble

   ```
   \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0116}{\.{E}}
   ```
2. Copy the offending character from the terminal output or log file and paste it in the first argument of `\newunicodechar`:

   ```
   \newunicodechar{Ė}{\.{E}}
   ```

Both ways should solve your problem.

Comment: Is there a difference between the two of them?

Comment: @fourreux No, I just find the second way more readable.