# How to use \DeclareUnicodeCharacter with U+302 for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, unicode, input-encodings

I am using a .bib file exported from Zotero with BetterBibTeX. I have activated the option `export unicode as plain-text latex commands` in the Better BibTex export options for BibLaTeX. I am stuck with pdftex and cannot swtich to XeLaTeX.

I was having errors regarding some unicode characters, such as ⟨:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ̂ (U+302)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I'm using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, and I could fix the trouble with the angled brackets by loading the `newunicodechar` package and adding the following definitions to my preamble [following this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173483/utf8-input-encoding-with-biblatex-biber-and-bibencoding-utf8):

```
\newunicodechar{⟨}{$\langle{}$}
\newunicodechar{⟩}{$\rangle{}$}
```

But how to do this for `U+302` as it is a compounding character? The citation is a French name with î in the name. The .bib file contains

```
author = {Lalanne, Jean-Beno{\^\i}t}
```

I tried with

```
\newunicodechar{î}{\^{i}}
```

but it does not recognize the command. Next up:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{302}{\^{}}
```

which makes the error disappear but the output is `Jean-Benoıˆt`. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If you use utf8 as inputenc and all your files are encoded accordingly, just input î in your bib file directly. This should do the trick. But I guess you want to use the bib entries that have been generated externally, right?

Comment: It's my own .bib file (utf8-encoded). I tried it, and the î shows correctly, but I still get complaint about `Unicode char ⟨ (U+27E8)`. So in a way it solved my problem with the circumflex.

Comment: Use `Beno{\^i}t` or, directly, `Benoît`. Since Biber is able to read Unicode, you may try not setting the “Unicode as plain-text LaTeX commands”.

Comment: Combining characters with `\i`/`i` are a bit tricky, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864. Not all unicode characters are recognised by `inputenc` out of the box, that is why you need code for the angled brackets.

Comment: Run `biber --output-safechars ...`

Comment: Any news here? Did you get anywhere? The `\i` issue is a known one, and so your question could be considered a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864 (or any of the other `\i` questions). But the question about the `⟨` could be more interesting. It would greatly help us if you could show us an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and update your question with your current approach.

Comment: Any news here? Is your question a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251261/35864 or do you need more?

Comment: Any news? Is there anything that could be done here?